# MySQL: Is there a way to eliminates duplicate entries from the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named "message" that stores messages from one user to another user. I want to make a message box that contains both **incoming and outcoming** messages for particular user. This message box should be contain the last message between two users. So, I have to eliminate duplicate messages between two users. I tried `group by` and it eliminates duplicate messages but I don't pick the most recent message because `order by` works after `group by`. I tried `distinct` function to eliminates duplicate messages. It works well, but I have to select all colums which isn't possible with `distinct`

My message table:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+------------+
| id    | from_id | to_id| text| created_at |
+-------+---------+------+-----+------------+
| 1     | 1       | 2    | mes | 2014-01-16 |
| 2     | 2       | 1    | mes | 2014-01-17 |
| 3     | 1       | 3    | mes | 2014-01-18 | 
| 4     | 3       | 1    | mes | 2014-01-19 |
+-------+---------+------+-----+------------+
```

My `Group By` SQL

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE (from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1) GROUP BY(from_id + to_id) ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

And `Distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT(from_id + to_id) FROM message WHERE (from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1)
```

In the above example, I want to select **second and fourth** message.

Is there a way to eliminate duplicate messages between two user from the result?

EDIT: I've improved the example

Comment: Why are you trying to add the id's?

Comment: there are no duplicate messages in your example table.  A duplicate message should have the same from_id AND the same created_at.  If these conditions is met,  then **GROUPING BY created_at** will select just one of the many messages you have,  mainly that fulfills the condition of having both identical values at _from_id_ AND _created_at_

Comment: You're misusing `GROUP BY`; it makes no sense unless you SELECT aggregate functions like MIN() or MAX().

Comment: @datelligent I've updated my question to be more clarify

Comment: @CanAydoğan,  why don`t categorize messages as _inbound_ and _outbound_ to to it`s nature,  that way is easier to select last one,  or to count messages by sender/receiver and by date.

Comment: @datelligent I want users to see all their messages in one list like facebook. I think, this approach is more useful than separating messages as inbound and outbound list

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you can leverage `LEAST()`, `GREATEST()` functions and non-standard `GROUP BY` extension behavior in MySQL like this

```sql
SELECT id, from_id, to_id, text, created_at
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, from_id, to_id, text, created_at 
    FROM message
   ORDER BY LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id), created_at DESC
) q
 GROUP BY LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id)
```

That will give you the last message row for each pair of users.

Output:

```
+------+---------+-------+------+------------+
| id   | from_id | to_id | text | created_at |
+------+---------+-------+------+------------+
|    2 |       2 |     1 | mes  | 2014-01-17 |
|    4 |       3 |     1 | mes  | 2014-01-19 |
+------+---------+-------+------+------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b264b/2)** demo

Answer (score 1):

*I tried group by and it eliminates duplicate messages but I don't pick the most recent message because order by works after `group by`*

So you can order it before:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY created_at DESC)
WHERE (from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1) GROUP BY(from_id + to_id);
```

Comment: It works great. But I wonder if there is a violation or issue with usage of `group by` like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

or by timestamp (assuming it contains data AND time):

```
ORDER BY create_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will sort all results in a descending order and only give you the last row.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple select.  There is no reason for duplicates to be created.

```
SELECT from_id, to_id, text, created_at
FROM message
WHERE
(from_id = ? AND to_id = ??)
OR (from_id = ?? AND to_id = ?)
```

Here `?` represents one id and `??` the other.

There would be no duplicates here. Ordering can be achieved in a few ways:

Order by most recent message regardless of sender:

```
SELECT from_id, to_id, text, created_at
FROM message
WHERE
(from_id = ? AND to_id = ??)
OR (from_id = ?? AND to_id = ?)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Order all sender message first (then by created_at)

```
SELECT from_id, to_id, text, created_at
FROM message
WHERE
(from_id = ? AND to_id = ??)
OR (from_id = ?? AND to_id = ?)
ORDER BY from_id = ? DESC, created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a HAVING clause after your GROUP BY:  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

or

SELECT 
    columns names,        COUNT(*)
 FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            column names
         FROM
            message

```
    ) 
    message
```

GROUP BY

column names
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13057/5)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE message
    (`id` int, `from_id` int, `to_id` int, `text` varchar(3), `created_at` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO message
    (`id`, `from_id`, `to_id`, `text`, `created_at`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 'mes', '2014-01-16 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, 1, 'MUL', '2014-01-17 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1
ORDER BY created_at DESC
limit 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13057/5/0)**:

```
| ID | FROM_ID | TO_ID | TEXT |                     CREATED_AT |
|----|---------|-------|------|--------------------------------|
|  2 |       2 |     1 |  MUL | January, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```